# How to arrange data in a file java

Tags: java

I produced an output file from a previous program which is as below:

firstName, LastName, 3.5

firstName2, lastName2, 1.4

(goes on for 200 more names)

But since its not in an array I'm not sure how to arrange the details in order of the integer. From the above example(1.4,3.5) so the output is:

firstName, LastName, 1.4

firstName2, lastName2, 3.5

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Without seeing the code that produced this, it's hard to help you to make it work. Can you please edit your question and add in the *relevant* sections of code? (don't just put it in the comments, the formatting here is impossible to read).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your class comparable by implementing the interface:
 - Comparable, and ovewrite the method compatreTo, hashCode and EqualsTo. OR
 - Comparator and overwrite also thoses methods.

Andyou can add your instances in a Collection i.e an Array and call

```
Collections.sort(yourCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider writing a class,e.g. person, which extends comparable. Adding on sorted data structures or which can be sorted should do the trick.

Examples of classes to consider:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

sorted structures:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html